# Can I create a snapshot of a VM to use for another one?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have a windows 10 VM and I forgot to take a snapshot of it before installing all of my tools. So my question is, can I create another win 10 VM, take a snapshot of it (just a clean installation without any additional software installed), and then use this snapshot as a base one for my actual VM with all the tools installed.

(Btw I use VMWare Workstation Pro)

Comment: Please see [what to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow.